# How to display multiple lines in a tableView cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a somewhat long string that gets truncated when displayed in a tablView cell. I did this to make the table view wider:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 100;
```

How can I make the font smaller as well as wrap the text in the table view cell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can set a few properties on the textLabel (or descriptionLabel, depending on what style of cell you're using) to do this.  Set `font` to change the font, `linkBreakMode` to make it word-wrap, and `numberOfLines` to set how many lines max (after which point it truncates.  You can set that to 0 for no max.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMyCellID];
    if( aCell == nil ) {
        aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kMyCellID] autorelease];

        aCell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];
        aCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; // Pre-iOS6 use UILineBreakModeWordWrap
        aCell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;  // 0 means no max.
    }

    // ... Your other cell setup stuff here

    return aCell;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know the only thing deprecated in iOS6 is `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`.  `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` is the iOS6 equivalent.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMyCellID];
    if( Cell == nil ) {
        Cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kMyCellID] autorelease];

       Cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size:10.0];
       Cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
       Cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;  // 0 means no max.
    }

  // your code here

    return Cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UITableViewCell and make it have a UITextView instead of a UITextField. Then assign your subclass to your UITableView.